# How to execute EventListener script on the element that was clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm learning vanilla javascript after using jQuery for quite some time. I'm trying to find the javascript equivalent of this:

```
$('.element').click(function(){
 $('.element').style("background-color","white");
 $(this).style("background-color","red");
});
```

This is what I've come up with so far:

```
document.querySelector('.element').addEventListener('click', event => {
  var y = document.getElementsByClassName('element');
  for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    y[i].style.backgroundColor = "white";
  }
  this.style.backgroundColor = "red";
});
```

What do I need to do to get the `this` keyword to work as I am expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My interpretation is that you have multiple elements but the way you've written it you're targeting a single element `querySelector('.element')`. This will only get you the first `.element`.

You can try something like this? Simple enough. Just use the **event**.

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll(".element");

function updateBgColor(e) {
  elements.forEach(el => {
    el.style.background = "white";
  });
  e.currentTarget.style.background = "red";
};

elements.forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener("click", updateBgColor);
});
```

```css
body {
  background: grey;
}

.element {
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="element">Click me</div>
<div class="element">Click me</div>
<div class="element">Click me</div>
<div class="element">Click me</div>
<div class="element">Click me</div>
<div class="element">Click me</div>
<div class="element">Click me</div>
<div class="element">Click me</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your jQuery version you are using a `style` method which I don't think it exists. I guess it's a typo and you meant [`css`](https://api.jquery.com/css/), but correct me if i'm wrong.

Supposing that the previous is true and you are calling jQuery `css` method there are a couple problems with your code translation.

First, the statement `$('.element').click(function(){` adds a click event to every element in the DOM with `element` class. With `document.querySelector('.element').addEventListener('click', event => {` you are only adding the click event to the first matched element. See [querySelector documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).

If you want to add an event for every element, you should query them with [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and iterate over the collection to add the event listener.

Second, if you don't use an arrow function to define the handler, you should have the HTMLElement where you clicked on the `this` attribute. Alternatively, if you want to use an arrow function, you could use `event.currentTarget` to get the element in which the user clicked.

Taking these into account you could use:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.element');
elements.forEach(function(element) {
    element.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        elements.forEach(function(elem) {
            elem.style.backgroundColor = "white";
        });

        this.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    });
});
```

or alternatively, if you want to use arrow functions:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.element');
elements.forEach(function(element) {
    element.addEventListener('click', event => {
        elements.forEach(function(elem) {
            elem.style.backgroundColor = "white";
        });

        event.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    });
});
```